# What's wrong with this HQL? Where is the missing comma?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I'm getting this hibernate exception:

```
 org.hibernate.QueryException: , expected in SELECT [select tc.id as
 id, tc.terminalServerPort.id as terminalServerPortId,
 tc.terminalServerPort.terminalServer.name as terminalServerName,
 tc.terminalServerPort.terminalServer.ipConfig.ipAddress as
 terminalServerIpAddress, tc.terminalServerPort.portNumber as
 terminalServerPort from
 com.windriver.dsm.labmanagement.data.TargetConsole tc where
 tc.target.id = :targetId order by id asc]
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: cany yyou show us the hql- query please?

Comment: What do you mean? this is the HQL query.

Comment: The Query in your java source code?!

Comment: @Jens means the query you wrote in your source code. This is the query Hibernate generates.

Comment: ... no it isn't, that is the HQL that Hibernate does not like which will be the query that is in the code :/ But I agree, better to see it in the context of the code rather than in the log. I don't see anything wrong with it as posted above.

Comment: The query is generic - it takes hqls by parsing it from a .xml file.
This is the line that throws the exception `Query query = hibernateSession.createQuery(hql);` Where hibernateSession is of `org.hibernate.Session`

Comment: Ok, but... which is the value of the hql var?

Comment: This is the 'hql' var value I'm seeing when debugging that line - `select tc.id as id, tc.terminalServerPort.id as terminalServerPortId, 
     tc.terminalServerPort.terminalServer.name as terminalServerName, 
     tc.terminalServerPort.terminalServer.ipConfig.ipAddress as terminalServerIpAddress, 
     tc.terminalServerPort.portNumber as terminalServerPortNumber 
     from TargetConsole as tc where tc.target.id = :targetId order by id asc`

Comment: Even when I narrow the HQL to the minimum I still get that exception - `, expected in SELECT [select tc.id as id from com.windriver.dsm.labmanagement.data.TargetConsole as tc]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

Apparently the hibernate version which I'm using (hibernate 3) **does not allow assigning aliases to associated entities**. When I remove those aliases - the query works.

Here is the correct code:

```
select tc.id, tc.terminalServerPort.id, 
tc.terminalServerPort.terminalServer.name, 
tc.terminalServerPort.terminalServer.IPConfig.IPAddress, 
tc.terminalServerPort.portNumber 
from TargetConsole tc where tc.target.id = :targetId order by id asc
```

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: You removed the order by clause (you were using id without the alias).

Comment: @LluisMartinez thanks, I edited my answer to include the order by clause.

Answer (score 1):

`Even when I narrow the HQL to the minimum I still get that exception - , expected in SELECT [select tc.id as id from com.windriver.dsm.labmanagement.data.TargetConsole as tc]`

Shouldn't you write it this way?

`[select tc.id as id from com.windriver.dsm.labmanagement.data.TargetConsole tc]`

Why are you writing `as` when giving alias to table?

Comment: Technically it is more correct, but the 'as' way also works. At least in JPQL it does, I admit I'm not 100% sure if it works in HQL too.

Comment: It works both ways according to [hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your hibernate translator property for the sessionFactory which you are using.

```
hibernate.query.factory_class = org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
```